# Issue in removing extra characters from string python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string given as:

```
text = """'select \\"ORDER_ID\\",\\r\\n    \\"LINE_ID\\",\\r\\n    \\"PRODUCT_ID\\",\\r\\n    \\"CUSTOMER_ID\\",\\r\\n    \\"PAYMENT_METHOD\\",\\r\\n    \\"STATUS\\",\\r\\n    \\"DATETIME_ORDER_PLACED\\",\\r\\n    \\"DATETIME_ORDER_SHIPPED\\",\\r\\n    \\"ORDER_QTY\\",\\r\\n    \\"ORDER_AMOUNT\\",\\r\\n    \\"ORDER_COST\\",\\r\\n    \\"ORDER_VAT\\",\\r\\n    \\"SHIPPING_COSR\\"\\r\\nfrom \\"DEMO\\".\\"DEMO\\".\\"ORDERS\\""
```

I am trying to clean this using below code:

```
text = text.replace("\\", '').replace('"', '')
```

I got the following result:

```
'select ORDER_ID,rn    LINE_ID,rn    PRODUCT_ID,rn    CUSTOMER_ID,rn    PAYMENT_METHOD,rn    STATUS,rn    DATETIME_ORDER_PLACED,rn    DATETIME_ORDER_SHIPPED,rn    ORDER_QTY,rn    ORDER_AMOUNT,rn    ORDER_COST,rn    ORDER_VAT,rn    SHIPPING_COSRrnfrom DEMO.DEMO.ORDERS
```

I cannot figure out why I am getting  **rn**  with every word. How I can get rid of this ? I even tried using `text = text.strip('\r\n')` but it is not working.

Comment: Pro-tip: never sanitize SQL inputs yourself.  How are you getting those characters in your string in the first place?  Is it feasible to clean your data upstream?

Comment: It would be better if you post your desired output. I would surely provide you a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```py
text = query_text = 'select \\"ORDER_ID\\",\\r\\n    \\"LINE_ID\\",\\r\\n    \\"PRODUCT_ID\\",\\r\\n    \\"CUSTOMER_ID\\",\\r\\n    \\"PAYMENT_METHOD\\",\\r\\n    \\"STATUS\\",\\r\\n    \\"DATETIME_ORDER_PLACED\\",\\r\\n    \\"DATETIME_ORDER_SHIPPED\\",\\r\\n    \\"ORDER_QTY\\",\\r\\n    \\"ORDER_AMOUNT\\",\\r\\n    \\"ORDER_COST\\",\\r\\n    \\"ORDER_VAT\\",\\r\\n    \\"SHIPPING_COSR\\"\\r\\nfrom \\"DEMO\\".\\"DEMO\\".\\"ORDERS\\"'
print(text.replace('\\"', '"').replace('\\r', "\r").replace("\\n", "\n"))
```

Output:

```
select "ORDER_ID",
    "LINE_ID",
    "PRODUCT_ID",
    "CUSTOMER_ID",
    "PAYMENT_METHOD",
    "STATUS",
    "DATETIME_ORDER_PLACED",
    "DATETIME_ORDER_SHIPPED",
    "ORDER_QTY",
    "ORDER_AMOUNT",
    "ORDER_COST",
    "ORDER_VAT",
    "SHIPPING_COSR"
from "DEMO"."DEMO"."ORDERS"
```

You get these kinds of strings for example when you call the repr function on a string:

```py
print(repr('''new line:
'single quotes',"double quotes"'''))
```

Output:

```
'new line:\n\'single quotes\',"double quotes"'
```

Escaping is commonly used on the web.

Comment: thanks working . can you please tell any reference from which I can read this topic further  ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to replace `\\r\\n` first. You can do that by

```py
text = text.replace("\\r\\n", '').replace("\\", '').replace('"', '')
```

Comment: thanks for reply . I am getting  SHIPPING_COSRfrom  . but I want this From seprate with space. why it's not adding space here ?

Comment: There is no space in your original string, how would the space get there?

Comment: You've just stripped these characters from the string, but they had a purpose. You needed to unescape them

Comment: The question seems to be unclear then, I understood the question to ask how to remove the newline characters...